# Open push notification and go to a view

Tags: ios, delegates, push-notification

I get a notification and after this I want to jump to my `ProfilViewController`.
The problem is, that I am currently on a VC1. How can I do that?

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
ProfileViewController* mainController = (ProfileViewController*)  self.window.rootViewController;
}
```

This is my currently function that should work (says the internet), however it doesn't. I am on every launch after the push on the same VC1 view controller.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted assigns the current rootViewController to a temporary variable called mainController, which is then promptly disposed of, since the method exits, and nothing refers to it ever again.

I assume you meant to do something more like this:

```
ProfileViewController *mainController = [[ProfileViewController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = mainController;
```

Comment: tanks for your quick response. Now I get a black screen. Also not so good. Should I import somewhere the appDelegate or something else?

Comment: Does ProfileViewController have a nib?  Is it defined in a storyboard?  Are you doing work in awakeFromNib instead of initWithNibName?

Comment: it is definitely in the storyboard and I found the solution:     `UIViewController *viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProfileView"];` BUT it just works on iOS 6 and today I test it in iOS 7 and there it doesn't work.